Unable to install packages on Pycharm
I am trying to install either tmdb3 or tmdbv3api for a project i am working on. I'm using pycharm as my IDE and I have a windows laptop. But I keep facing errors when I try to download it and I do not know what to do. I installed both using my command prompt and I believe everything worked well with that. The problem is when I try using it in pycharm. Also sorry if my terminology is incorrect, this is my first time using pip install and im not a coding expert.
First I run this:
import pip
pip.main(["install","tmdbv3api"])
import tmdbv3api

and I get error
C:\Users\moloj\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\moloj\OneDrive\Documents\movie rec\movie_sent_analysis_v2.py" 
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Collecting tmdbv3api
  Using cached tmdbv3api-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\moloj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tmdbv3api) (2.27.1)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\moloj\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\requests-2.27.1.dist-info\\METADATA'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\moloj\OneDrive\Documents\movie rec\movie_sent_analysis_v2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tmdbv3api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tmdbv3api'

Process finished with exit code 1

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pip on my command prompt but this didnt work.
second I try on the console:
pip install tmdbv3api

and I get this:
C:\Users\moloj\anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.4/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=52941 
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\moloj\\OneDrive\\Documents\\movie rec', 'C:\\Users\\moloj\\PycharmProjects\\movie_sent_analysis'])
PyDev console: using IPython 8.15.0
Python 3.9.18 (main, Sep 11 2023, 14:09:26) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
pip install tmdbv3api
Collecting tmdbv3api
  Using cached tmdbv3api-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\moloj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tmdbv3api) (2.27.1)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\moloj\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\requests-2.27.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

I've restarted my laptop and pycharm multiple times.
**
Finally, I try adding it manually through python packages on pycharm**
again I get an error saying:
Processing c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tmdb3-0.7.2

ERROR: file://C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tmdb3-0.7.2 does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

Any help will be appreciated, I've been going around in circles for ages

Try to add it using the Python Packages tool window or the Python interpreter settings.

I got these errors: `Collecting tmdbv3api
Using cached tmdbv3api-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\moloj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tmdbv3api) (2.27.1)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\moloj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests-2.27.1.dist-info\METADATA'`

and:
`[1 lines of output]
ERROR: Can not execute setup.py since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
Encountered error while generating package metadata.
See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.` when trying to follow these steps

Make sure that PyCharm is using the correct virtual environment or create a new one and then Update pip and Reinstall both requests and setuptools

This blog may help.
